# Attachment in chat doesn't open (item not found), but clicking on file in Files Tab does

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

We have migrated our messages and attachments from Slack to Teams and are encountering an issue where attachments sent in channels don't open ("The item might not exist or is no longer available"), however when you go to the Files tab for that channel, the file opens just fine.

I used the TeamsMigrate tool from GitHub - https://github.com/chkp-roniz/teams-migrate

Any advice on what I can do to resolve this issue?

Looking at the browser DevTool > Networks, when clicking the attachment in chat the "GetListItemByResourceId" ID value is different from the ID when clicked in the Files Tab.

Looking at the repo, I cannot identify where it is getting this resourceID from

Comment: We tried the above by following the [Import third-party platform messages to Teams using Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/graph-api/import-messages/import-external-messages-to-teams). We POSTed a message with inline image and it is being opened properly. Also please note that Currently, inline images are the only type of media supported by the import message API schema.

Comment: Thanks Meghan; so to confirm, office docs (docx, pdf, etc) are not supported during message importation?

Comment: Yes, Currently, inline images are the only type of media supported by the import message API schema - https://i.stack.imgur.com/BLoXq.png

Answer (score 0):

Currently, inline images are the only type of media supported by the import message API schema - [image]